# Use git orphan as folders and keep history

Tags: git, orphan

I have a few projects in different repositories that I want to unite under the same repo with different orphan branches.
for that, I have created a new repository and starting it inside.

1. How do I take an existing repo, import it as an orphan branch and keep the history?
2. Is it possible to work with 2 orphan branches opened as different folders? Let's say that I have 2 orphan branches and I want to work on both of them in parallel, possible? I have much more than 2 and I want to work with single git UI opened so it will be more efficient to develop. Today I check out each repository. after I unite it under the same repo, I still need to work on all branches in parallel.

```
orphan-branch-B
              \.gitignore
              \.README.md
              \ and more

orphan-branch-B
              \.gitignore
              \.README.md
              \ and more
```

Comment: Have you tried git submodule?

Comment: @einverne thanks, but each submodule is a different repo, I want to avoid that.

Comment: If you want to work on all branches in parallel, the best way is to split project into different module. Git can keep all your history, but you still have to frequently check out different branches.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### TL;DR

> I have much more than 2 [branches] and I want to work with single git UI opened ...

Whether that's possible, and if so, how, depends on the UI.  Asking about Git in general won't get you an answer to that.  The command-line answer is to use `git worktree` (for which Git 2.15 or later is highly desirable).

#### Long

> 1. How do I take an existing repo, import it as an orphan branch and keep the history?

You don't, really.  This operation—and question—probably makes no sense, because I doubt you mean *orphan branch* in the way that *Git* means it.  Read on to the end to decide if it does make sense.

#### What is a Git repository anyway?

A Git *repository* consists, in essence, of two databases.  One database simply holds Git *objects*, of which the most interesting one is the one called a *commit*, and each commit represents a complete snapshot of all files.<sup>1</sup>  The other database holds *names*—branch names like `master` and tag names like `v2.1`—and those names are how you, and at least initially Git, will *find* interesting commits.

Each commit—which, again, represents a *snapshot* of all files; commits *do not* contain changes—is uniquely identified by its hash ID.  The hash ID is a big ugly string of letters and digits that appears random, but is actually a cryptographic checksum of the entire contents of the commit: the snapshot, plus the metadata that tells you who *made* the snapshot (name and email address), when (time-stamp), why (log message), and so on.  Because each commit stores the actual hash ID of its immediate predecessor or *parent* commit, it's easy for Git to start with the *last* commit and work backwards:

```
... <-F <-G <-H   <-- master
```

Hence a *branch name* like `master` simply holds the hash ID of the *last* commit in the branch.  The history itself is just the chain of commits formed by starting with that commit—`H` in this example—and working backwards, one commit at a time, from commit to parent.

There's a slight hitch here because chains are not necessarily linear.  Having made a sequence of commits like the above, we might also have a second sequence of commits:

```
          G--H  <-- master
         /
...--E--F
         \
          I--J   <-- develop
```

Here, commits `F` and earlier are on *both* branches, while commits `G-H` are *only* on `master` and `I-J` are *only* on `develop`.  If we then *merge* `J` into `master`, we get a commit that's slightly special:

```
          G--H
         /    \
...--E--F      K  <-- master
         \    /
          I--J   <-- develop
```

While commit `K` has a simple snapshot as usual, it now has *two* parents, not one, making it a *merge commit*.  To view the history from `K`, we must go back to commits `H` *and* `J` *both*, at the same time.  From there we go back to `G` *and* `I`; from there we go back to `F`, where the history re-converges, having diverged at the merge.

In other words, Git works backwards: history logically converges at a merge, and since Git works backwards, history actually *diverges* at a merge.  History logically diverges at the point where you spun off a second branch, but in Git it actually *converges* at that point, because Git works backwards.

What makes a *branch name* like `master` special is that it *always points to the last commit that we wish to say is on the branch*.  This is particularly important because you are asking about *orphan branches*.

---

<sup>1</sup>The other three object types are *tree* (trees hold file names), *blob* (each blob is a file's contents), and *annotated tag* for tags like `v2.1`.  Git uses the commit + tree + blob combination to construct the snapshot that each commit represents.

---

#### How Git makes new commits: the index and the work-tree

> 2. Is it possible to work with 2 orphan branches opened as different folders?

If you have Git 2.5 or later—with 2.15 or later being a good idea due to some bugs in the initial implementation in Git 2.5—you can use `git worktree` to work with two different branches at the same time, in two different *work-trees*.  It's now time to talk about Git's *index* and *work-tree* notions, after which we'll get to the definition of an *orphan branch*.

Everything in a Git commit snapshot is frozen forever.  No part of any commit—not its log message, not the user name, not the parent hash ID, and no part of *any* saved file stored *as* part of that commit—can be changed.  **Nothing about any existing commit, identified by some existing hash ID, can ever be changed.**  All of its files are frozen in time.  (They're also compressed, sometimes very compressed.  You can think of them as being freeze-dried, if you like.)  This is great for archival: you can go back in time to any previous commit, any time you want.  But it's useless for getting any *new* work done.

To let you get work done, then, Git gives you the ability to *check out* a commit.  Checking out a commit does three things:

1. The first and most obvious is that it kind of "re-hydrates" a freeze-dried commit, extracting all of its files to some sort of work area where they have their normal, non-frozen, non-Git-ified form.  This work area, which is normally right next to the repository itself, is your *work-tree* (or working tree, or sometimes working directory or some variant of this kind of spelling.)
2. The second, also obvious once you think about it, is that if you use `git checkout master` or `git checkout develop` or whatever, is that it remembers *which branch name you used to get the latest commit from that branch*.  Or, if you used `git checkout <hash-id>` to go back in time, it remembers the hash ID.  Either way—by branch name or by hash ID—it remembers which *commit* you have out, too.
3. The third, mostly-invisible, thing that `git checkout` does here is to fill in Git's *index*.

Calling this thing *the index* is kind of a useless name—what does *index* convey after all?—so it has two more names as well: it's sometimes called the *staging area*, or sometimes the *cache*, depending on who or which part of Git is doing this calling.  All three names are for the same single thing, though.  What the index is and does gets a little complicated during merges, but the main thing it is and does is that it holds all the files from a commit, in their Git-ified form, *ready* to freeze, but—unlike a real commit—*not actually frozen*.

What this means is that the index holds all the files that will go into the *next* commit.  In other words, it's sort of a proposed next commit.  You start with:

```
git checkout master
```

and for each file that *was* in the commit identified by the name `master`, you now have not two but *three* copies of that file:

- `HEAD:file` is the file stored in the commit.  It *can't* be changed: it's Git-ified, frozen, and read-only.  Use `git show HEAD:file` to see it.
- `:file` is the file stored in the *index*.  It *can* be changed!  It's Git-ified, but you can *replace* it with a new copy, any time you want.  Use `git show :file` to see it.
- `file` is the file stored in your work-tree.  It's an ordinary file, and you can do anything you want with it.  Use ordinary (non-Git) commands to see or change it or do whatever you want.

If you've *changed* some file like `file`, and you want Git to store the *new* version in the *next* commit, you must now update your proposed next commit:

```
git add file
```

This *copies* the work-tree file into the index, overwriting `:file` with a newly Git-ified copy of your file `file` from your work-tree.

Hence, *the index always contains the proposed next commit*.  You update this proposal by using `git add`.

Note that if you `git checkout` some other branch, you *replace* the next-commit proposal with a different proposal that matches the commit you just checked out.  (There are a few exceptions to this rule, on purpose; see [Checkout another branch when there are uncommitted changes on the current branch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22053757/1256452).)  This, in turn, means that the index and the work-tree are really a pair: the index *indexes* the work-tree.  When you make changes to the work-tree, by changing some files around, you need to update your index by `git add`ing those files.

When you run `git commit`, what Git does is this:

- save your name and email address;
- save the current time (the timestamp for the new commit);
- collect a log message from you, to go into the new commit;
- use the *current* commit's hash ID as a parent hash ID;
- save all of this, plus the Git-ified files in the index, into a *new* commit, which automatically gets a new hash unique hash ID (by computing a cryptographic checksum over all of this data)
- write the *new* commit's hash ID into the *current branch*

That is, if you had:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master
```

you now have:

```
...--F--G--H--I   <-- master
```

The *name* `master` now records the hash ID `I` of the new commit you just made.  That new commit has as its *parent* the hash ID of commit `H`, the one you had checked out before you made this new commit.

That's *how* history is formed!  Making a new commit, which Git just made from whatever is in the index *right now* when you ran `git commit`, creates our new commit `I`.  The new commit's parent is the commit you had Git check out.  Because Git made the commit *from* the index, the index and the new match, just as they did when you first ran `git checkout master` to get commit `H`.  Everything now looks good for you to modify stuff in the work-tree, use `git add` to copy it back into the index, and run `git commit` to make a new `J` whose parent is `I` and whose saved snapshot comes from the index.

#### Making a new branch

Now that you know how existing branches work, let's look at the process of making a *new* branch.  Suppose we start with commit `I` that you just made on `master`:

```
...--F--G--H--I   <-- master
```

Let's make a new branch named `feature/short`:

```
git checkout -b feature/short
```

What we have now looks like this:

```
...--F--G--H--I   <-- master, feature/short (HEAD)
```

That is, *both names*—both `master` and `feature/short`—identify existing commit `I`.  The special name `HEAD`, which Git uses to remember *which branch we're on*, is attached to the name `feature/short`.

Now we'll mess with the work-tree as usual, run `git add` as usual, and run `git commit`.  Git will collect our name and email and the time, our log message, and so on, and make a new commit `J` with the snapshot from our index and with parent `I`.  Then it will write `J`'s actual hash ID, whatever that is, into the name `feature/short`:

```
...--F--G--H--I   <-- master
               \
                J   <-- feature/short (HEAD)
```

The *history* starting at `J` goes back to `I` and then `H` and so on.  The new *commit* is at the tip of the new branch, `feature/short`.  Our index now matches both our commit `J` and our work-tree, and `HEAD` remains attached to our branch `feature/short`.

You now know everything there is to know about branches—well, except for *orphan* branches, which we'll get to in a moment.

#### Adding work-trees

If you have been paying close attention, you will have realized by now that not only does the "index" index the work-tree, both it and the work-tree also have an intimate relationship with the special name `HEAD`.  We use `git checkout` to attach our `HEAD` to some branch name, and in the process, we fill up our index and our work-tree with everything from one particular *commit*, the one at the *tip* of that branch—the commit to which the name points.  All of these entities—`HEAD`, index, work-tree, and branch-name—change simultaneously.

What `git worktree add` does is to create a *new* triple—a new <HEAD, index, work-tree> group—and run `git checkout` in that new group.  The new work-tree must reside in a *different area in your computer:* a different folder, if you like the term *folder*.  The newly added work-tree is on a *different branch*.  All work-trees must be on different branches, even if those branch *names* identify the same commit!  Each work-tree has *its own* index and `HEAD`, and if you switch from one work-tree to another, you must change your idea of your `HEAD` and your index.

The files inside each *commit* are all freeze-dried: Git-ified and compressed, and not useful.  The files extracted into a *work-tree* are rehydrated and useful.  So the ability to add *more* work-trees means that you can have different commits out at the same time, as long as they're out in different work-trees.

(As a special case, any work-tree can have a *detached HEAD* where you extract a specific commit by hash ID.  So if you need to look at sixteen different historic commits, you can add 16 work-trees, each on a different detached HEAD on that historic commit, for instance.)

#### Orphan branches

Now that we have all of that out of the way, we can—finally!—look at what an *orphan branch* is.  It's less than you think!

We already know that `HEAD` is normally attached to some existing branch name, and existing branch names store the hash ID of one single commit, which we call the *tip* of that branch.  When things are set up this way, making a *new* commit updates the *branch name*, so that it the existing branch name now stores the new, unique commit hash ID of the new commit we just made.

We've also mentioned, in passing, that `HEAD` can instead store the hash ID of a commit—Git calls this a *detached HEAD*.  Here `HEAD` is *not* attached to a branch name, hence the word "detached".  The index and work-tree work in the usual way here: the index holds all the files from the detached-HEAD commit hash ID, in their freeze-dried form but not actually frozen any more, and the work-tree holds all the files from that commit.  You can make a new commit this way too: if you do, Git just stores the new commit's hash ID into the name `HEAD`.  No *branch* name remembers this hash ID.  Only `HEAD` holds that hash ID.  These commits are easy to lose by mistake!  If you use `git checkout` to move your `HEAD`, you've lost the hash ID of the new commits you made—so be at least a little careful with a detached HEAD, so as not to you lose your head. :-)

There's one more mode, though, for `HEAD`.  Git allows you to attach your `HEAD` to *a branch name that doesn't exist*.  To do that, you use `git checkout --orphan`:

```
git checkout --orphan feature/tall
```

This works a lot like `git checkout -b`.  But `-b` first *creates the branch name*, and *then* attaches `HEAD` to the branch name.  It's the *creation* of the branch name that stores a hash ID inside the name!  When we made `feature/short` above, we *created* the name pointing to existing commit `I`, the same commit that `master` already remembered.

When we use `git checkout --orphan`, Git *doesn't create the branch name*.  We end up with a picture like this:

```
...--F--G--H--I   <-- master
               \
                J   <-- feature/short

feature/tall (HEAD)
```

The contents of the *index* and the *work-tree* remain unchanged, exactly as before, but the *name* `feature/tall` does not exist as a *branch name* at all.  It's just that `HEAD` is attached to it.  Since it doesn't exist as a branch name, it doesn't point to any existing commit.

If we make a commit right now, Git will save, as a new snapshot, the contents of the index.  If we didn't change anything, those contents match commit `J`.  So we'll get a new commit `K`.  The *parent* of new commit `K` is supposed to be whichever commit we have checked out right now—the one identified by the branch name to which our `HEAD` is attached.  But that branch doesn't exist!

What Git does here is to do the same thing it does for the very first commit you make in a new, totally-empty repository that has no commits yet.  Git simply makes the commit with *no parents at all*.  Such a commit is called a *root commit*, and we can draw it like this:

```
K
```

Having made the new commit, Git now updates the branch name to which our `HEAD` is attached.  That name is `feature/tall`, so now we have:

```
...--F--G--H--I   <-- master
               \
                J   <-- feature/short

K   <-- feature/tall (HEAD)
```

The new branch, `feature/tall`, now exists.  It has sprung into existence *because* we made a new commit—as always, from the index—and that new commit **has no history**.

History, after all, *is* just the chain of commits, starting at wherever and working backwards.  We start at `K` and work backwards—well, there's nowhere else to go.  So we start at `K` and show the commit and we're done.  End of history!  There's nothing else there.

Now, of course, if we start at `J` or `I` and work backwards, there's history *there*.  But it's not connected to the history we get starting at `K` and working backwards.  So `feature/tall` is an orphan branch.  It's just an unrelated-to-everything branch.

This peculiar property is very useful in a new, totally-empty repository.  Such a repository has no commits and no branches, and the very first commit we make—by creating some files, copying them into our initially-empty index, and committing—should be the first and only commit *in* this still-new but now not-empty repository.  If our `HEAD` was attached to the branch name `master`—which of course it was—this *creates* our first branch name, `master`, pointing to the first and only commit, which we can call `A` but which has a unique hash ID that's a cryptographic checksum of the contents of the files we created plus our name plus our email address plus the log message we entered plus the very *time* when we ran `git commit`, all of which add up to making this commit unique in the universe.

Using `git checkout --orphan` sets up similar conditions, except that the index and work-tree are probably not *empty*.  Making the first commit for this orphan branch is what creates the orphan branch.  The *snapshot* that goes in is, as always, whatever is in the *index* when you run `git commit`.  The log message is whatever you enter.  The new commit has *no* parent, which is why Git calls it an orphan.

#### Conclusion

If you wanted an orphan commit, this is how you get it.  But it has no history, by definition, because history *is* the chain of parents.  If you want an orphan, you get no history; if you want history, you may not use an orphan.

Comment: Pheeeeew, I just saw it on my mobile... will read at the weekend (its holiday). thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for "git worktree"...

1. (optionally) create a bare repository; e.g.

   ```
   mkdir .repo/
   git clone --bare .../project .repo/project.git
   ```
2. create the worktrees from within this repository

   ```
   git -C .repo/project.git worktree add `pwd`/project-A branch-A
   git -C .repo/project.git worktree add `pwd`/project-B branch-B
   ```

You can skip step 1 and create worktrees from existing, non-bare repositories, but imho it eases operations the branched projects are long living.

Comment: Ok. but what about using an orphan branch from existing source? can you please also put some more info on the commands? what is `.../project` please add some more explanations.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can remove everything, commit that, and start from the tip. Or cherry-pick an orphaned branch on top of it.

```
git rm -rf .
git commit -m 'remove everything'
```

Answer (score 0):

> git worktree: but what about using an orphan branch from existing source? can you please also put some more info on the commands?

This is not yet supported, but in [active discussion/implementation](https://public-inbox.org/git/20221212014003.20290-1-jacobabel@nullpo.dev/T/#m3e8b7b1c0d530e119779952b487dfa9ca507e33d)

> ### adding orphan branch functionality (as is present in `git checkout`) to `git-worktree add`
>
> Adds support for creating an orphan branch when adding a new worktree.
> This functionality is equivalent to git checkout's `--orphan` flag.
>
> The original reason this feature was implemented was to allow a user
> to initialise a new repository using solely the worktree oriented
> workflow.
>
> Example usage included below.
>
> ```bash
> $ GIT_DIR=".git" git init --bare
> $ git worktree add --orphan master master/
> ```

It is listed in the [latest "What's cooking in git.git"](https://public-inbox.org/git/CAPc5daWvYANBvwc_zQh7FqR0Y-vJ4eP75LMigqc-4RjBW+Pnfw@mail.gmail.com/T/#m3d3708afd25be9c6701383d7c0ff42a255b9cc84), but not yet officially merged to `master`.